# Proving regularity properties from forcing axioms

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, descriptive-set-theory

It's well known that PFA implies projective determinacy. It's also well known that PD implies that all projective sets are Lebesgue measurable, have the Baire property, etc.

Is there a direct proof of "all projective sets of reals are regular" from PFA (i.e. without relying on determinacy)?

Comment: Using large cardinals: You use failure of square principles to get (a sufficiently iterable) $M_\omega^\sharp$, that allows you to realize $L(\mathbb R)$ essentially as a Solovay model. (But I imagine this is *not* what you are asking.)

Comment: Interesting question; I feel like the answer is more likely to be yes if the conclusion is replaced by "after collapsing $\omega_1$, all projective sets of reals are regular" (but I still don't know what a proof would look like.)  One could also consider the weakening where "all projective sets of reals are regular" is replaced by "there is no projective well-ordering of the reals."

Comment: So you're asking how to prove from $\sf PFA$ directly that every projective set is universally Baire?